# How can I change the "frequently used" emojis in Discord?

Tags: discord

I am a new Discord user. I am using the Windows 10 client. It has helpfully populated some "frequently used" emojis for me and shows them to me every time I want to use an emoji. These are without exceptions emojis I would not use and in some cases would rather not see (poop, rude faces etc.)

I have tried just patiently using the emojis I like to use. It's been a few weeks and none have moved into the "Frequent" zone. I have tried right-clicking on some (hoping there might be "remove from this list") but nothing happens. I cannot find any settings related to this.

Can this be done?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this currently but there is a [feedback idea](https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land/suggestions/19334812-remove-emotes-from-frequently-used) for this you can vote on

Comment: Looking at my list of 'frequent' emoji, it seems they are all emoji that I actually type out e.g :shrug: or :thumbsup:. It's possible that it just shows frequently typed emoji?

Comment: @MichaelFrank: [yes](https://superuser.com/a/1657874/33589), but this is really annoying UX.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Discord is chrome-powered. Hit control/cmd + shift + i to open up the
> chrome debugger tools. Hit Application tab. At the side, find the
> Storage column, open up Local Storage, and click on the discord url.
> These are all the stuff that Discord saves (including your password
> token - do not share pls thx). There is a key named `EmojiStore`
> if you clear the stuff to the right and reload discord with
> ctrl/cmd+r, it will be cleared. Otherwise, if you know how to
> manipulate JSON data types, you can litterally remove :frogface: from
> the history.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/79icxx/location_of_file_for_frequently_used_emojis_please/dp33x49/

For the JSON, it'll look something like this:

`{"100":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"eggplant":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"fork_and_knife":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"yum":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},}`

So to remove "eggplant", for example, you'll want to delete the text starting from "eggplant" to the curly brace and comma that comes after "score".

`{"100":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"eggplant":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"fork_and_knife":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50},"yum":{"totalUses":1,"recentUses":[1514823987052],"frecency":50,"score":50}}`

Comment: well, deleting the key didn't work. I guess I might have to figure out how to edit json

Comment: This worked. I used Edit Value then Ctrl A Ctrl C and pasted it into a file with a .json extension. I then removed all except the 100 which I can tolerate, using a text editor. Then copied it all, back to Discord, again right click Edit Value Ctrl A but this time pasted the reduced text. And now I have only the 100 in my frequent. I may add some that I use a lot to the list if they don't put themselves there. Thankyou!

Comment: Also, I sent a message that consisted only of a handful of emojis I like to use. I typed them, in case that matters, and they all promptly added themselves to the list.

Comment: @KateGregory I don't think it matters whether you type them or select them, as long as they are part of a message rather than a reaction to one; I had an emoji I frequently used as a reaction that never appeared on the list, but using it once like you suggested in a message popped it into the list, whether I typed one or selected one.

Comment: Amazing.. finally fixed the thumbsup that I use 100x more often than everything else but would never show up in frequently used. FYI Local Storage key is called `EmojiStore` now. Edit the field then press Ctrl+R to refresh Discord. I used this to delete the nodes I didn't want: https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor

Comment: Why is this still necessary in 2020?

Comment: Any explanation as to why the Discord app on macOS doesn't seem to accurately reflect my recently-used emoji? I'm always having to search for `thumb` to get the one I want. I’m going to try to add it to the EmojiStore, but what a pain. EDIT: didn't work

Comment: Seems the thumbsup and related emoji don't work, but others do.

Comment: I simply deleted the `EmojiStore` key completely and reloaded Discord. Aftwards, I got an emoji list which actually reflects my frequently used emojis.

Comment: Did the same as @Ignitor and it worked for me as well.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete. Discord seems to be using "EmojiStoreV2" which has a new structure that isn't compatible with this answer. Anyone have info on how Discord handles the frequent emoji now?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to mess around in Local storage, there is a simpler trick to manipulate your Frequently used emojis list, as suggested by [Kate Gregory](https://superuser.com/users/41443/kate-gregory) in [comments](https://superuser.com/a/1287972/16858).

The first thing to understand is that this is a *Frequently used emojis in messages* list, not a *Frequently used emojis in messages and reactions* list, so using emojis to react to a message doesn't alter the emoji *use count* at all!

Knowing this, it becomes clear that to promote your preferred emojis into the list, just post a message with lots of copies of your preferred emoji, then delete your message. Keep repeating this until your preferred emojis are at the top of the "Frequently used" list.

If you want to remove emojis off the list entirely, then you will want to pick and promote any emojis below them in the list, and then add enough other emojis that the ones you don't want are pushed off the end of the list.